# Can a KML file include simple logic?

Tags: kml

Just started working with KML files, and I'm trying to find if there's any way of including very simple logic within a file?

I create daily KML files which include links to external files (pdf's, excel sheets etc). I produce a great number of files every day, current files are created and stored on a high speed SSD drive, but due to space constraints they get moved to a traditional magnetic HDD after a few days.

Moving the files means the links no longer work. Can I incorporate simple logic to link to a different file location after X days?

Cheers

(my current solution is to edit the KML files to edit the links when the files get moved - but I have lots of large files and this can take a while)

Answer (score 0):

If your links are just to external files like PDFs and spreadsheets, and are not to other KMLs in Earth, then you should be able to do this by using some JavaScript in your balloons.  With that you should be able to modify the URLs shown as links in the balloons, based on the date/time.